# WAMP 403 on Multiple Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp

I have two folders:

```
c:wamp:www  // My root  
c:wamp:coll // Alternative
```

In my `www` folder i have `.htaccess` for my CodeIgniter application so i can have url's like so `site.com/controller/method`

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

I want to run collaborator application in coll and my ci in www this is how i setup my `httpd.conf`

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <directory "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/coll/"
    ServerName project.localhost
    <directory "c:/wamp/coll/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have all required modules active:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And my `hosts` file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    project.localhost
```

Error log:

```
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1872
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Child process is running
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:11 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:15 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:15 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:16 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Released the start mutex
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:17 2013] [notice] Child 1872: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:17 2013] [notice] Child 1872: Child process is exiting
[Fri Jan 18 23:30:17 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:31 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:31 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5380
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:32 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Child process is running
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:32 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:32 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:32 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:32 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:41 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:41 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:42 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Released the start mutex
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:43 2013] [notice] Child 5380: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:43 2013] [notice] Child 5380: Child process is exiting
[Fri Jan 18 23:41:43 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/wamp/coll'] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
```

Comment: I can find the question or spot an error but Hey! you should use 2 different subdirectories of c:/wamp/www/ like **c:/wamp/www/codeigniter** & **c:/wamp/www/collaborator/**

Comment: I cant have two deperate directories in wamp root ?

Comment: ... Thus, you used virtual hosts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I have ever seen virtual hosts that parted ways before you even get into a common web directory (like www), but if I were attempting this, and getting 403s, I would look at the extra DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" at the top of your document there - looks like an open base directory violation to me. Your apache error logs should have more specific information about why it is returning a 403.

Without seeing the error logs, I would try changing that first document root declaration to:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/"
```

But like I said, I don't know why you would want to host pages outside of www - I believe that is there for security reasons.

Comment: However if i open project.localhost i get no problems only problem i get is when i visit localhost then i get the 403. Change to DocumentRoot did not help

Comment: Are you restarting apache after making changes to httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

for localhost no need to add  items.

it should work like this.

```
# your vhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@your.vhost.domain
    DocumentRoot "your.vost.doc.root"
    ServerName your.vhost.domain
    ErrorLog "logs/your.vhost.domain.log"
    CustomLog "logs/your.vhost.domain-access.log" common
    <Directory "your.vost.doc.root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
# Localhost
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www # wamp doc root
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

*your.vhost.domain must be changed to your own.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.